# Using maven dependencies on Eclipse plug-ins

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I would like to use a maven dependency in my Eclipse plug-in. What I've done so far is I added the dependency on my pom:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung</groupId>
    <artifactId>lutung</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And when I try to use the dependency I get the run time exception below (omitted the stack trace):

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microtripit/mandrillapp/lutung/MandrillApi
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microtripit/mandrillapp/lutung/MandrillApi
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microtripit.mandrillapp.lutung.MandrillApi cannot be found by myplugin_1.0.0.qualifier
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The artifact you are referencing is not an OSGi bundle, so it cannot be used directly in a Tycho build. You need a separate build step first that converts the artifact to an OSGi bundle.

Comment: @oberlies I see, how can i build one? I found an example on eclipse website but it only works with the given example library

Comment: Are you interested in OSGi wrappers in general, or do you only want to use the `lutung` library? This is not clear to me when reading the question.

Comment: @oberlies in general, lutung was just an example.

Comment: You use pom-first approach or resolves dependencies trough MANIFEST.MF files ?